# Why use require './foldername/filename' over require 'foldername/filename'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In many blogs and articles I've seen the same pattern. In node.js when we used `require()`, we use the following:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

In the image below you can see that for `routes` and `users` this idiom is being used.

Can someone explain me why we use `./`?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you use `var routes = require('routes/index');` node try to read module from `node_modules/routes/index` (in most cases). `./` mean current directory of this file.

Answer (score 1):

**Because that's just how it is**

Read the [module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

There's no catch-all magic way for node to determine wether a `"foo/bar"` is a relative path or the name/component of a module.

To make this clear node has a very explicit convention in place for loading files and modules

- Files are loaded with explicit paths such as `"./foo"`, `"../../bar"`, or `"/path/to/foo"`
- Modules are loaded by name/identifier such as `"foo"` or `"foo/bar"`

Comment: all that means is modules are known/cataloged by the application and file paths are not.

Comment: @JohnPeters modules are not "known/cataloged", the lookup is very explicitly described in the documentation.